# Angular Bootstrap Slider - on stop execute function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code for creating a slider:

```
 <html ng-app="angular-bootstrap-slider-test">
    <head>
        <title>Angular Bootstrap Slider test</title>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>

  <body ng-controller="TestCtrl">
       <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
          <slider on-stop-slide="executeMe();" ng-model="sliders.sliderValue" min="{{testOptions.min}}" step="{{testOptions.step}}" max="{{testOptions.max}}"></slider>
         {{myFormater(sliders.sliderValue)}}
       </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<!-- angular-slider include -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
<!-- test file include -->
<script src="app.js">
</script>
```

```
angular.module('angular-bootstrap-slider-test', ['ui.bootstrap-slider'])
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.sliders = {};
    $scope.sliders.sliderValue = 50;

    $scope.testOptions = {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
    };



    $scope.sliders.thirdSliderValue = 0;
    $scope.myFormater = function(value) {
        return value + "%";
    }

    $scope.executeMe = function() {
       console.log('done');
    }
}]);
```

What i'm trying to do with no success is to execute a function when the user finishis to to move the slider

here is the code on plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/iULltHh0fRAbvuoFu84t?p=preview

Thanks allot

Avi

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngMouseup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseup) for that.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2" ng-mouseup="executeMe()">
    <slider  ng-model="sliders.sliderValue" min="{{testOptions.min}}" step="{{testOptions.step}}" max="{{testOptions.max}}"></slider>
        {{myFormater(sliders.sliderValue)}}     
</div>
```

Here's [your plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kv10MXnR9J46u6VVKy7P?p=preview) modified to demonstrate.

**Update**

A different approach will be to `$watch` the slider's value. You can set a timeout so you don't trigger your function while sliding, but only when the value has not changed for some time.

```
var timeout;
$scope.$watch('sliders.sliderValue', function() {
    if (timeout) {
        $timeout.cancel(timeout);
    }
    timeout = $timeout($scope.executeMe,200);
});
```

See [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TBas5BU0uyLNbg6bBvF0?p=preview)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks but this executes even if the value hasn't changed.

Comment: ng-mouseup will *not* fire if you mouse up outside of the component - i.e. drag the slider but move the mouse pointer down the page, the slider is still active and dragging, if you then release the mouse button you do not get a mouseup fired.