# angular.element is not working in tabset directive of angular js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using tabset directive of angular js and using twitter bootstrap slider in tab,

My slidestop event is not calling but it's working well outside tab.

I know that tabset directive have its own scope , but dont know solution of following problem:-

```
<tabset class="tab-container">
    <tab heading="tab1">
               <div class="form-group">

                   <label>any Level</label>

                   <div class="input-group w-md">
                        <input id="slider" ui-jq="slider" ui-options="{min: 0,max: 10,step: 1,value: {{any_level}}}"
                       class="slider slider-horizontal form-control" type="text"
                       ng-model="any_level"> {{any_level}}

                  </div>
               </div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

controller code

```
 ......
angular.element("#slider").on('slideStop', function(data){
       alert('asdasd');

 })
```

problem is - alert is not coming when slider inside tab,alert is comming when slider outside tab

i am using [this slider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider)

Thanks

Comment: So what is not working ? You just say that it work outside, but tell us how it behave inside.

Comment: @Okazari alert is not coming when when i change slider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have solved using ui-event directive to fire slidestop event

Html Code

```
<input id="slider" 
        ui-event="{slideStop: 'alertChange($event)'}"  ui-jq="slider" 
        ui-options="{min: 0,max: 10,step: 1,value: {{any_level}}}"
        class="slider slider-horizontal form-control" type="text"  ng-model="any_level">


{{any_level}}
```

Controller Code

```
$scope.alertChange = function(data){
   console.log(data.value); // i can get slider value on slidestop

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use `angular.element` in an angular app.

**EDIT : This isn't really working with ui-slider. Till ui-slider is work in progress i just woudn't use it.**

Add this to your input :

```
ng-change="alertChange()"
```

And this to your controller :

```
$scope.alertChange = function(){
   alert('hi');
}
```

What wasn't working ? In most of the case an `angular.element` will try to bind your even to the element too early. Your DOM "#slider" element isn't probably loaded when your try to bind.

**EDIT An alternative :**

First, after paying more attention i wouldn't recommend this slider at all.
This is actually a work in progress and isn't really reliable.

I made you an exemple of a html slider with binding in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gj1NM5QFDJXS3oUTgkkh?p=preview)

You slider looks like this :

```
<input id="slider" 
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 100 }" 
       min="0"
       max="100" 
       ng-init="any_level = 0" 
       ng-change="alertChange()"
       type="range" 
       ng-model="any_level">
```

This will update the model each time the value will not change for 100miliseconds. You need this to avoid firing too much ng-change function.

In your javascript you just need to declare your function

```
$scope.alertChange = function(){
   console.log("I changed !");
   //or anything else you want to do
}
```

I know this is not a solution but an alternative. It's not sexy as the other slider, but at least it works.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: You could use this approach with `ng-mouseup` instead, or a $watch with a timeout as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710485/angular-bootstrap-slider-on-stop-execute-function

Comment: @seanhodges - slideStop event give me slider value,i am not getting value in ng-mouseup

angular.element("#slider").on('slideStop', function(data){
--- i can receive value from data.value

Comment: It's difficult to know why you're stuck doing things the wrong way without knowing which slider solution you are using. Angular modules usually have `ng-click`-style attributes that allow you to attach to an event at the correct time in the load lifecycle.

Comment: @kishor Added a plunker with a working exemple with a html slider input. This is an alternative but i can't make your slider working...

Comment: @seanhodges Actually this ui-slider isn't working great. I doubt that it will fire ng-change and ng-mouseup. But that was a good suggestion.

Comment: @Okazari thanks for your efforts,i have post my answer

Answer (score 0):

The slider you are using has an example demonstrating how to do this. Take a look at box "12" on this page: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-slider/demo/demo.html

In your controller you can add the following:

```
$scope.slider = {
    'options': {
        stop: function (event, ui) { $log.info('Slider stop'); }; 
}
```

And your HTML you must reference `slider.options` so your callback is fired:

```
<div ui-slider="slider.options"
     min="0" max="50" ng-model="any_level"></div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I tried this too, but i can't make it too work. Does this slider have any documentation on how to use the directive ?

Comment: The documentation seems to consist of the source code and that demo page I linked above. To be honest, as @Okazari suggested, this particular slider project feels unfinished and probably isn't ready for prime time, hence no documentation.